# Deterministic approximation algorithms for treewidth

Tags: reference-request, approximation-algorithms, derandomization, treewidth

As far as I understand, the factor $O(\sqrt{\log OPT})$ approximation algorithm for treewidth of [Feige, Hajiaghayi, and Lee](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/05064299X) is randomized, and no deterministic approximation algorithm with this factor is known. Is this correct? Is any deterministic approximation algorithm with factor below $O(\log OPT)$ known?

Comment: Are you sure that the FHL algorithm cannot be derandomized?

Comment: I'm not sure at all - in fact i would not be *that* surprised if someone points to some paper that derandomizes FHL -- i just haven't been able to find anything like that. If such a derandomization is folklore or follows from a folklore trick i would very much like to know.

Comment: I would look at this paper to see if the techniques apply. The ARV rounding is more complicated of course so I am not sure whether it would actually work. http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539796309326

Comment: Just to be sure I understood the scheme of the FHL algorithm, isn't it that the randomised part lies in the J. Bourgain's result?